# QTP: Why is a PDF page in an IE not a Page object (as all other pages are)?

Tags: testing, qtp, gui-testing

When looking at an IE web page with QTP 10, Object Spy reports a Browser object containing a Page object containing other elements. Okay.

Now if I view a PDF in that very same browser, that page is recognized as a WinObject object contained in a Browser object.

No Page object, no nothing.

This is not limited to the spy. If you try to address the page containing the PDF from the QTP script, it fails. You must address the WinObject object.

**Why?**

It is (of course) displayed as if it was a page like every other page, just containing an ActiveX control.

I believe that earlier versions of QTP indeed found that, and not a generic WinObject object.

Adobe Reader version installed is 9.2.0. IE is 7.0.5730.13.

Comment: I bet it is a bug in the web add-on. Or a consequence of the fact that the pages in IE are no real pages of a tabbed notebook, but an optical fake for that. AND of the fact that QTP handles browser pages like standalone browser instances -- you can enumerate browsers with ChildObjects, and you will get as many browsers as you have pages, no matter how many separate browser instances you have. Which is strange, but good -- because a given script can address pages and browsers independently of the IE settings for tabbed browsing. Everything works even if you disable tabbed browsing. I think.

Comment: What's wrong with this question -- almost no views, and absolutely no answer candidates, not even an insulting comment? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Downvoter: Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the ActiveX addin loaded and associated with your test under File -> Settings to recognise it using the OR/GUI Spy.

Comment: No -- glad that it helped AND delivered your first reputation points.